# com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin in React native crash report

Tags: android, react-native, crash-reports

I have uploaded one build for internal testing. There is a report for all the crashes. It says that

```
java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
```

Does anyone is familier with this problem?

I have tried to look for it on the internet but no specific solution found.